# Sonar Qube report generation either as csv,xml or pdf

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using **sonarqube-7.3** version. I want to make report from sonarqube either as csv, xml or pdf. I have googled it and found that we can make pdf report using sonar-pdfreport-plugin. I have dowload the version s**onar-pdfreport-plugin-1.4** and pasted it in the extension/pluggin folder. But I can't restart the server. Anyone please provide a solution for getting report for the version provided above.

Comment: You can find all deprecated plugins [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Deprecated+Plugins). PDF Report is one of them and is not updated since 2015. Since that time, a lot has been adapted to SonarQube so you cannot use this pluging with the latest SonarQube versions. If you do want to pay for the enterprise version the best way to go is using the Web API to get the needed information and create you own report.

Answer (score 1):

In general, SonarQube is not meant to be used as some reporting tool, but more as part of CI pipeline and users can use it's UI to manage code quality issues.

However, PDF reporting is available in the commercial Enterprise Edition of SonarQube for portfolios (groups of projects) as part of Governance. You can find details here https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/enterprise/

The plugin you are mentioning is most likely not updated for the 7.3 version

Comment: I got a csv report from the link: https://docs.codescan.io/hc/en-us/articles/360012009891-Exporting-your-issues-as-a-CSV-file.

Comment: I need to deactivate the default rule. I'm using community edition of sonar qube. Can I make it I can't find anything from the UI provided

Comment: @MelvinMoses please ask separate question for that issue